# Php переменные из файла в классе

Tags: php

Добрый день, работаю на PHP, есть класс, Example, и я в него хочу загрузить, приватные переменные из другого файла (который содержит только переменные), т.е. логика такая:

```
class Example {
    include (constant.php);

    function f1()
    {
        return from_const;
    }
}
```

Но, само собой, это не правильно, если инклудить в конструкторе, то видимость переменных только для конструктора, а мне-бы желательно для всех функций, есть ли какое-то решение? Переменных много, поэтому в конструкторе переприсваивать их переменным класса не рационально чтоль.

Comment: Возможно тут лучше использовать трейты http://php.net//manual/ru/language.oop5.traits.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> загрузить, приватные переменные

запятая не нужна

> это не правильно

неправильно

> мне-бы

мне бы

> есть ли какое-то решение

[@sergiks](/users/7161/sergiks) все правильно написал. Если же у вас настолько хитрая архитектура, что подгрузка из файла обязательна:

data.php

```
<?php return array(
    'a' => 'b',
    'c' => true,
);
```

someclass.php

```
class Someclass
{
    private $data;
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->data = require 'data.php';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Так включайте не в конструктор, а, как вы и написали, с теле класса. Как выглядит ваш включаемый файл? Если как ниже, то какие проблемы?

```
private $Aaa = 'aaa';
private $Bbb = 'bbb';
// ...
private $Zzz = 'zzz';
```

Comment: потому что include класс воспринимает как функцию, и следовательно выдает ошибку.

Comment: Вы правы, `include()` в теле класса вызывает `Parse error`.

Почему бы не наследовать все эти классы от одного, где определены все эти переменные?